# When to use Rationalisation to solve limits.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

As the title suggests, when do we have to solve limits using rationalization?

The problem is that they are lengthy and tricky to solve... l'hopital takes care of them easily.
Most of them can be solved mentally using l'hopital

When do we have to use l'hopital and when do we have to use rationalization? Examples would be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide examples of when *you* think it is better to use rationalization, and when it is to use L'Hopital? Use the problems you have come across and struggled with/solved using one of these approaches. Being more specific (is rationalization/L'Hopital better for one/two specific problems) gets you better answers, and some will generalize like you desire.

Comment: Usually for limits with $\frac{0}{0}$ forms that involve square-roots.

Comment: I avoid rationalization because they are too lengthy to type or write. It's much simpler to use the limit formula $(x^n-a^n) /(x-a) \to na^{n-1}$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: If the sole purpose is to come up with the limit, it is fine to use L'Hopital wherever it works (and it actually applies - don't try to use it unless you know the limit is a $\frac 00$ or $\frac \infty\infty$ form). It is a theorem. The results it gives are accurate. So why do many exercises disallow its use? For the same reason schoolchildren are still required to learn how to do arithmetic manually instead of just trained in how to use calculators. L'Hopital does not always work. You need to also learn other techniques, and get a better feel for limits in general.